# Delete Hash from URL and refresh without 404 error - Angular 4.3.2 - JHipster

Tags: angular, spring, refresh, jhipster

I have a project made with JHipster generator, Angular 4.3.2 and Spring.

All of this in a Monolithic application

In the development area I'm using node for the routing and nginx for the production area.

This project in the url have a hashtag symbol after the url

> http://example.com/#

I want to navigate in my single page app without that symbol and also refresh the page without getting 404 not found error.

I made the app to work without the symbol replacing all of this

```
RouterModule.forRoot... {useHash: true}
```

To this

```
RouterModule.forRoot... {useHash: false}
```

How can I make the app refresh to work without getting error 404?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are all of the changes made to remove the hash from the URL for the Angular client. https://github.com/ruddell/jhipster-examples/commit/2c31cf65eea96d45c8ed63845e2d96b04fb4b29f

The important parts are as follows:

1. Add `ClientForwardController` which forwards all unmapped backend routes (anything not an API endpoint) to index.html

```
    @Controller
    public class ClientForwardController {
        /**
         * Forwards any unmapped paths (except those containing a period) to the client index.html
         */
        @GetMapping(value = "/**/{path:^(?!websocket)[^\\.]*}")
        public String forward() {
            return "forward:/";
        }
    }
```

2. Change the base href in index.html to `/`, if you deploy under a context path you will have to configure this value in [webpack.common.js](https://github.com/ruddell/jhipster-examples/blob/2c31cf65eea96d45c8ed63845e2d96b04fb4b29f/webpack/webpack.common.js#L95)
3. For nginx in production, you have to configure it to send unhandled URLs to index.html.  [As documented](https://www.jhipster.tech/separating-front-end-and-api/#using-nginx), here's an example that proxies to the API and otherwise sends to index.html:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://api.jhipster.tech:8081/api;
    }
    location /management {
        proxy_pass http://api.jhipster.tech:8081/management;
    }
    location /v2 {
       proxy_pass http://api.jhipster.tech:8081/v2;
    }
    location /swagger-ui {
        proxy_pass http://api.jhipster.tech:8081/swagger-ui;
    }
    location /swagger-resources {
        proxy_pass http://api.jhipster.tech:8081/swagger-resources;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```